# Постановка тире между подлежащим и сказуемым

Tags: пунктуация, тире, сказуемые, подлежащее

Имеются три группы предложений на тему, заданную в заголовке. Не могу понять правило и различия постановки знаков препинания. Прошу выделить **составные именные сказуемые** и объяснить это правило более понятно для каждого случая отдельно.

**А**

1. Сладковатый запах водяных лилий смешан с запахом смолы.
2. Солотча извилистая неглубокая река.

**Б**

1. Жизнь прекрасна и удивительна.
2. Основной мотив моей жизни сделать что-нибудь полезное для людей.

**В**

1. Ольга старшая сестра Виктора.
2. Слепая ненависть плохой советчик.

*Буду безмерно благодарен.*

Comment: Можно проверить. Здесь безмерно рады проверять.

Comment: Автор, вам намекают, что стоит попробовать самостоятельно сделать это задание и опубликовать результаты - тогда местное сообщество поможет вам найти ошибки, если они будут.